# EclipseLink annotation error

Tags: eclipse, jpa, eclipselink

I have generated some entities from an existing database and I have added the jars - elipselink.jar and javax.persistence_2.2.0.v201708071007.jar to build path -> Configure Build Path. I have 14 entities and 14 errors:

> Class "model.Attribute" is listed in the persistence.xml file, but is not annotated

even though the "import generation" has added the @Entity annotation:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Attribute.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM Attribute a")
public class Attribute implements Serializable {
```

All of the entities have this error with their class name underlined in red. What have I done wrong?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="IdpCertificateValidate">
        <class>model.Attribute</class>
        <class>model.Company</class>
        <class>model.ComplexityRule</class>
        <class>model.ComplexityRulePattern</class>
        <class>model.ComplexityRulePatternPK</class>
        <class>model.PasswordPolicy</class>
        <class>model.Role</class>
        <class>model.User</class>
        <class>model.UserAttribute</class>
        <class>model.UserAttributePK</class>
        <class>model.UserFailedLogin</class>
        <class>model.UserFailedLoginPK</class>
        <class>model.UserPasswordHistory</class>
        <class>model.UserPasswordHistoryPK</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok very strange I added "one" `@Table(name = "Attribute")` tag and all the errors went away. I then removed the `@Table` annotation and the errors did not return.