# After javax.persistence -> jakarta.persistence Spring Boot Upgrade, error: "Class .. is listed in the persistence.xml file, but is not annotated"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040208/class-is-managed-but-is-not-listed-in-the-persistence-xml-file), but no recent comments. I don't want to turn off JPA validation in Eclipse, I want to get to the bottom of how to resolve this warning:

**Summary:** We upgraded Spring Boot **2.7 -> 3.0.2**. In the entity classes we replaced `javax.persistence.*` with `jakarta.persistence.*`. In some of our entity classes, as soon as that was done, this error popped up:

```
Class ".." is listed in the persistence.xml file, but is not annotated
```

Reverting the `jakarta.persistence.*` back to `javax.persistence.*` removed this error, but we need to update to Jakarta for Spring Boot 3.x.

We have a `persistence.xml` file which lists the managed entities.

```
<persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>model.MyData</class>
    <class>model.MyDataError</class>
    <class>model.StoredProcedureResultBean</class>   
 </persistence-unit>
```

All classes listed in `persistence.xml` are annotated with **@Entity**. There are none that are not.

Any tips?

Comment: I see that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48909250/eclipselink-annotation-error there is a similar question. Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: No, haven't been able to. On the command line when I do "mvn clean install" everything's fine so I just disregard that.

Comment: I understand, but then it is not a problem that prevents you from continuing with your program

Comment: It doesn't prevent me from continuing, but since Eclipse is my IDE, it's unpleasant and confusing to see this incorrectly flagged.

Answer (score 0):

As this does not affect code functionality, we've just disabled the (annoying) error message in Eclipse / STS:

Settings -> Java Persistence -> JPA -> Errors/Warnings:

On the Errors/Warnings page: Select dropdown option Ignore for the error "Class is listed in the persistence.xml file but is not annotated"

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently working on an application with WildFly 31 and Java 21. I was using Eclipse 2023-12.
Although the entities were annotated using the @Entity annotation and mapped in the persistence.xml, eclipse kept signaling the error: "Class "br.com.joaogabriel.drugstore.entity.Address" is listed in the persistence.xml file, but is not annotated". However, the application ran normally, the server started without console errors and other operations ran normally.
What resolved it for me was to disable this validation performed by Eclipse.

Preferences -> Java Persistence -> JPA -> Errors/Warnings -> Persistence Unit:

- Class is listed in the persistence.xml file but is not annotated: Ignore